# Remove historical trailing white spaces in Git

Tags: git

What is the simplest solution to fix committed white space issues like trailing white spaces to an existing repo?

Comment: fix the whitespace issues and commit them? if you haven't pushed yet, you will be  better off with `git commit --amend`; for the future you might enable the default `pre-commit` hook, which protects against trailing whitespaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have existing commits in your repo with trailing whitespaces, then you would need to change those commit (rewite history), which can be painful if that repo is already push and cloned by others.

But if that is an option, then you can use a script like the [one in gitolite](http://gitolite.com/the-list-and-irc/whitespace-index-filter.html):

```
#!/bin/bash

# from doener (who else!)
# to be called as an index-filter

if git rev-parse --quiet --verify $GIT_COMMIT^ >/dev/null
then
        against=$(map $(git rev-parse $GIT_COMMIT^))
        git reset -q $against -- .
else
        # Initial commit: diff against an empty tree object
        against=4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904
        git rm --cached -rfq --ignore-unmatch '*'
fi

git diff --full-index $against $GIT_COMMIT | git apply --cached --whitespace=fix
```

> run this like:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter '. ~/git-scripts/ws-fix.sh'
```

Answer (score 4):

Just discovered in the git-docs (to be tested) :

```
git-rebase --whitespace=fix
```

could also be an option.

See :

- http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#Formatting-and-Whitespace
- http://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply

Answer (score 1):

I would have preferred to add this as a comment to the already accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18076464/13613140) but I just registered to share my findings and do not have enough reputation yet.

If rewriting history (and thus changing all commit hashes) **is** an option, then a filter script like the one from the mentioned answer seems to be the best approach. However when I tried do use the `ws-fix.sh'` script from there, the `map` function was not available. From a quick view into a recent [source](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/git/git/+/refs/tags/v2.26.2/git-filter-branch.sh#20) of `git-filter-branch.sh` it seems that the `map` function is (by default) only available in the [`commit-filter`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/git/git/+/refs/tags/v2.26.2/git-filter-branch.sh#192) but **not** in the [`index-filter`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/git/git/+/refs/tags/v2.26.2/git-filter-branch.sh#183). Just to be sure I also tried to export the `map` function without success. What made it finally work for me, was to simply redefine the map function just within the filter `ws-fix.sh` script itself:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

map()
{
    if test -r "../map/$1"; then
        cat "../map/$1"
    else
        echo "$1"
    fi
}

if git rev-parse --quiet --verify $GIT_COMMIT^ > /dev/null
then
        against=$(map $(git rev-parse $GIT_COMMIT^))
        git reset --quiet $against -- .
else
        against=$(git hash-object -t tree /dev/null)
        git rm --quiet --force --ignore-unmatch --cached -r '*'
fi

git diff --full-index $against $GIT_COMMIT | git apply --cached --whitespace=fix 2> /dev/null
```

With this version I could apply the `index-filter` so far without issues:

```sh
git filter-branch --index-filter '~/ws-fix.sh'
```

I didn't test this on more complex repositories though. So make **always** sure to have a **backup** before testing!